# Google + Invalid redirect URI

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am using a slogin joomla extension.
creating a google plus developer account.
create a client id but error will be arise
**Error:**Invalid redirect URI.

**AUTHORIZED JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS:**
I am giving http://mylocal server ip address.
**AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URIS:**
In this field i am giving http://mylocal server ip address/folder/subfolder/?option=com_slogin&task=check&plugin=google
**ip address**:49.206.140.128

please give me a answer asap

Answer (score 0):

the only issue with slogin is uri mismatch.i just got it worked.

from joomla admin of your website,copy the exact "callback URL" (select by double clicking on it ) from google plugin and add that in uri in ur google app.

after breaking my head on this issue for almost a day,this is the solution which i got...DONT COPY the uri from error message on your browser.

Comment: i should be work on that same procedure.problem has not resolved